# Using the "rvest" library on whoscored.com

Tags: r, rvest

I've tried to use rvest on "whoscored.com" but I can't get to scrap any of the tables, for example the table here "https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/65/Show/Spain-Barcelona", I always get the error "Table = F" or empty characters. Anyone already tried it on a similar website? Thank you for your help.

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/341")
table <- html_nodes(page, "#statistics-table-summary") %>% html_table()
```

And I get this :

```
Error: html_name(x) == "table" not TRUE
```

Comment: You must post your code to get help.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question -- unfortunately I didn't have much luck myself. It seems to be peculiar to the website. Have a go at some of the examples in `?html_table`.

Comment: I used it on other websites, it works fine but this website is peculiar it doesn't work! Thank you for taking the time to try it, if you have any idea on how I can scrape those data feel free to let me know.